# checking if my array elements meet requirements

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, boolean

I need to create a method which checks each element in my array to see if it is true or false, each element holds several values such as mass, formula, area etc for one compound, and in total there are 30 compounds (so the array has 30 elements).  I need an algorithm to ask if mass < 50 and area > 5 = true .

My properties class looks like:

```
public void addProperty (Properties pro )
        {
        if (listSize >=listlength)
        {
        listlength = 2 * listlength;
        TheProperties [] newList = new TheProperties [listlength];
        System.arraycopy (proList, 0, newList, 0, proList.length);
        proList = newList;
        }
        //add new property object in the next position
        proList[listSize] = pro;
        listSize++;

        }

        public int getSize()
        {
        return listSize;
        }
        //returns properties at a paticular position in list numbered from 0
        public TheProperties getProperties (int pos)
        {
        return proList[pos];
        }
        }
```

and after using my getters/setters from TheProperties  I put all the information in the array using the following;

```
TheProperties tp = new properties();

string i = tp.getMass();
String y = tp.getArea();
//etc
theList.addProperty(tp);
```

I then used the following to save an output of the file;

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0; i<theList.getSize(); i++)
    {
        if(theList.getProperties(i).getFormatted() != null)
        {
            builder.append(theList.getProperties(i).getFormatted());
            builder.append("\n");
        }
    }           

    SaveFile sf = new SaveFile(this, builder.toString());
```

I just cant work out how to interrogate each compound individually for whether they reach the value or not, reading a file in and having a value for each one which then gets saved has worked, and I can write an if statement for the requirements to check against,  but how to actually check the elements for each compound match the requirements? I am trying to word this best I can, I am still working on my fairly poor java skills.

Comment: one thing I suggest is to define an array for each parameter, for example one array for Mass, one array for Area and so on, then the first element for each array represents the first object. You have more control this way.

If you are using Java 8 I suggest you check parallel arrays: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/ParallelArrays.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are after, I found your description quite hard to understand, but if you want to see if the mass is less than 50 and the area is greater than 5, a simple if statement, like so, will do.

```
if (tp.getMass() < 50 && tp.getArea() > 5) {}
```

Although, you will again, have to instantiate tp and ensure it has been given its attributes through some sort of constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, which makes it hard to answer.

You could check at creation time, and just not even add the invalid ones to the list.  That would mean you only have to loop once.

If you just want to save the output to the file, and not do anything else, I suggest you combine the reading and writing into one function.

```
    Open up the read and the write file
    while(read from file){
        check value is ok
        write to file
    }
    close both files
```

The advantage of doing it this way are:

1. You only loop through once, not three times, so it is faster
2. You never have to store the whole list in memory, so you can handle really large files, with thousands of elements.

Answer (score 0):

In case the requirements changes, you can write method that uses `Predicate<T>`, which is a *FunctionalInterface* designed for such cases (functionalInterfaces was introduced in Java 8):

```
// check each element of the list by custom condition (predicate)
public static void checkProperties(TheList list, Predicate<TheProperties> criteria) {
    for (int i=0; i < list.getSize(); i++) {
        TheProperties tp = list.get(i);
        if (!criteria.apply(tp)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "TheProperty at index " + i + " does not meet the specified criteria");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to check if mass < 50 and area > 5, you would write:

```
checkProperties(theList, new Predicate<TheProperties> () {

    @Override 
    public boolean apply(TheProperties tp) {
        return tp.getMass() < 50 && tp.getArea() > 5;
    }

}
```

This can be shortened by using lambda expression:

```
checkProperties(theList, (TheProperties tp) -> {
    return tp.getMass() < 50 && tp.getArea() > 5;
});
```

Comment: Thanks that is really interesting I will look into that.